# Writing a script for automating Curl operation in windows

Tags: windows, post, curl, git-bash

The task I want to perform is as follows. 
I want to read data from a web application on my local network (192.168.1.xxx) and save it as an xml file. This file has to be then sent as a POST request to a 3rd party server at regular instants of time **automatically**. All these tasks have to be done in a Windows OS. I can do all these tasks by executing curl commands in git-bash. But I'm having trouble executing this automatically at different instants of time. How can I do this? Can I write a script to do this and execute this script in the task manager? I also looked into cronjob for Windows. Using this I can probably open git-bash automatically. But I wont be able to input the necessary curl commands into it.

Any help on this will be really great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What format is the data coming from the source web app.

Comment: For questions about the OP it's generally better to use the comment field :)

Comment: It's in .xml format. eg 192.168.1.xxx/abcd.xml.  I'm able to save it as a file. No issues with that!